# In MVC, how do I get an instance of HtmlHelper from AjaxHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom control in my MVC 5 project.  At the end of it I want add on a Save button and a ValidationSummary (in the WriteSubmitControls method).  A Validation Summary is built using an instance of a HtmlHelper.  Seems like `HtmlHelper` and `AjaxHelper` should share a base class or interface, but they don't appear to.
How do I access an instance of HtmlHelper without passing it in?

```
public class MyCustomAjaxForm: IDisposable  
{  
    private readonly MvcForm _ajaxForm;

    public MyCustomAjaxForm(AjaxHelper ajaxHelper)  
    {
        _ajaxForm = ajaxHelper.BeginForm("Save", "Contacts", routeValues, ajaxOptions);
    }

    private void WriteSubmitControls()
    {
        _writer.WriteLine("<button type='submit'>Save</button>");
        // Output Validation Summary Here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        WriteSubmitControls();
        _ajaxForm.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, but not sure if it's the best way.  I create a new instance of `HtmlHelper` using the `ViewContext` and `ViewDataContainer` from the `AjaxHelper`.

```
public class MyCustomAjaxForm: IDisposable  
{  
    private readonly MvcForm _ajaxForm;
    private readonly HtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    public MyCustomAjaxForm(AjaxHelper ajaxHelper)  
    {
        _ajaxForm = ajaxHelper.BeginForm("Save", "Contacts", routeValues, ajaxOptions);  

        //create instance of HtmlHelper
        _htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(ajaxHelper.ViewContext, ajaxHelper.ViewDataContainer);
    }

    private void WriteSubmitControls()
    {
        _writer.WriteLine("<button type='submit'>Save</button>");  

        //output ValidationSummary using instance of HtmlHelper
        _writer.WriteLine(_htmlHelper.ValidationSummary(true));

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        WriteSubmitControls();
        _ajaxForm.Dispose();
    }

}
```